# Office 2013 - Installation without spellchecker

Tags: ms-office, spell-checking, office-2013

My dad works as a teacher in a school for disabled pupils. They have the need to write their test on notebooks. It was possible to install older office version without the spellchecking or at least to disable it. Is there a possibility to do so with office 2013 ? As he told me ..he tried to delete the spellchecking files but office reloads them directly ...

Hope you can help him / me ;)

Greets and a nice weekend

Ike

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use something other than office. Wordpad is a cut down Word that usually comes bundled with windows PCs, and WordPad doesn't come with spell-checking by default. If they just need to write the test without any fancy formatting, notepad should do the trick too. Other operating systems also have cut down text editors, e.g. leafpad for Linux.